# Crypotography from java security not working and throwing bad padding exception

Tags: java, cryptography

I have create a certificate using the keytool utility of java and trying to encrypt and decrypt the code but it is continuously throwing the following error;I tried every possible suggestion which i got from stackoverflow but nothing worked for me and i am stuck how to resolve :

Stacktrace:

```
    javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Data must start with zero
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(RSAPadding.java:325)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(RSAPadding.java:272)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:356)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:382)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2087)
```

Code

```
// Encryption code
protected byte[] encryptMessageWithPrivateKey(String aMessage) throws Exception {
    ByteArrayOutputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ByteArrayOutputStream resultStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] vEncoded = null;

    DataOutputStream outStream = new DataOutputStream(inputStream);
    outStream.writeBytes(Integer.toString(this.randomGen.nextInt()));
    outStream.writeBytes(":");

    outStream.writeBytes(this.mTimestampFormat.format(Long.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())));
    outStream.writeBytes(":");

    outStream.writeBytes(",");

    outStream.writeBytes(aMessage);

    DataOutputStream resultWriter = new DataOutputStream(resultStream);
    if (this.mEncryptCipher == null) {
        KeyStore privateKs = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        privateKs.load(new FileInputStream(new File(mPrivateCertFile)), null);
        KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry privateKeyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) privateKs
                .getEntry(mPrivateCertKey, new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(
                        mPrivateCertPassword.toCharArray()));
        PrivateKey privateKey = privateKeyEntry.getPrivateKey();

        System.out.println("encrypt private key : " + privateKey.getFormat());
        this.mEncryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        this.mEncryptCipher.init(1, privateKey);
        System.out.println("mEncryptCipher = " + this.mEncryptCipher);
    }

    byte[] vMyUnincryptedString = inputStream.toByteArray();

    resultWriter.write(this.mEncryptCipher.doFinal(vMyUnincryptedString));

    vEncoded = resultStream.toByteArray();

    System.out.println("Encrypt length : " + vEncoded.length);
    return vEncoded;
}

// Decyption code
protected byte[] decryptMessageWithPrivateKey(String aSecretMessage) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("aSecretMessage : " + aSecretMessage);
    byte[] vNoSecret = null;
    if (this.mDecryptCipher == null) {
        KeyStore privateKs = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        privateKs.load(new FileInputStream(new File(mPrivateCertFile)), null);
        KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry privateKeyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) privateKs
                .getEntry(mPrivateCertKey, new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(
                        mPrivateCertPassword.toCharArray()));

        PrivateKey privateKey = privateKeyEntry.getPrivateKey();
        /*
         * KeyPair keyPair =
         * KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA").generateKeyPair(); PublicKey
         * publicKey=keyPair.getPublic(); System.out.println("public key : "
         * +publicKey.toString());
         */

        System.out.println("privateKey = " + privateKey.getAlgorithm());

        this.mDecryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        /* .getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding"); */

        System.out.println("List of provider : ");
        Provider[] prov = Security.getProviders();
        for (Provider provider : prov) {
            System.out.println(" : " + provider.getName() + " ,Info : " + provider.getInfo());

        }

        this.mDecryptCipher.init(2, privateKey);
        System.out.println("mDecryptCipher = " + this.mDecryptCipher);
    }

    /* byte[]encryptText = HexToByte.hexStringToByteArray(aSecretMessage); */
    byte[] encryptText = TestConverter.afromHex(aSecretMessage);
    System.out.println("Encrypt lenght : " + encryptText);
    vNoSecret = this.mDecryptCipher.doFinal(encryptText);

    System.out.println("vNoSecret msg : " + vNoSecret.length);
    return vNoSecret;
}
```

Here for converting the string which i have converted to hexadecimal string after encrypting the byte and passed that hexastring to decrypt and here in decrypt method that string is converted back to byte and passed to doFinal method.
But throwing an error.I tried to change the padding to noPaading but then it show some unreadable block.I am confused where i am getting it wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at [this site](http://sscce.org/) to help you post better questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the concept of public key cryptography, and I'm not going to give a tutorial in this answer. I'll note a couple of things to hopefully point you in the right direction for further study.

1. You are attempting to encrypt using a private key and also decrypt using a private key. That can't work. You *encrypt* with the public key and *decrypt* with the private key.
2. Normally you encrypt *data* with a symmetric algorithm (like AES or ChaCha) using a randomly generated key *K*, and then you encrypt *K* with the receiver's RSA public key R<sub>pub</sub>. The receiver then decrypts *K* with their RSA private key R<sub>priv</sub> and then decrypts the data using *K* and the symmetric algorithm.

Comment: Note that some scenarios (digital signature), you need to encrypt with private key and decrypt with public key. In all cases, if you are using asymmetric cryptography, you can't use the same key for encryption and decryption.